# ASP.NET Web Api application with Html 5 video streaming. Web api method does not calling after host in server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, video-streaming

I used a sample code in my ASP.NET WebApi application for video streaming from Google. Search as 'asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api'.

I call web Api method from  tag to stream video.

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="api/sample/video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It works fine under my IIS local host. For example, call my Html page which contains `<video>` tag     http://localhost/VideoMediaPlayer/Media.html

It does not work when I hosted to my development server. For example, calling web page with fully qualified domain name.

For example:

http://devserver.app.com/VideoMediaPlayer/Media.html.

Actually, web api method does not call because I am not getting any error or exception.

My local computer IIS v7.5 and Dev server IIS v8.5.

I spent a lot of time and researched a lot but I could not figure out this issue.

Any kind of help, idea or hints would save my project delivery time.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide the website URL here?

Comment: i am sorry i cannot. It is not under company's policy.

Comment: I have an observation that if I turn off IE's proxy settings, it works. Anybody knows how can I run video with IE's proxy?